# How can I install the social sharing package in Ionic angular?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

Im getting the following error when using the ionic-native/social-sharing package:

```
Failed to initialize Angular compilation - The target entry-point "@ionic#6421-native/social-sharing" has missing dependencies:
 - rxjs/Observable
 - rxjs/observable/fromEvent
 - rxjs/observable/throw
```

I have rxjs installed.
Also, when I installed the ionic-native/social-sharing I had to use --force, else it wouldnt install. Not using --force gave the following error:

```
could not resolve dependency npm err peer rxjs 5.5 11 from ionic-native core 4.20 0
```

What can I do to solve this? All I want to do is use the @ionic-native/social-sharing package

EDIT:
After deleting node_modules and doing npm i, I get this error when I npm i:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: @ionic-native/core@4.20.0
npm ERR! Found: rxjs@7.5.7
npm ERR! node_modules/rxjs
npm ERR!   rxjs@"~7.5.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer rxjs@"^6.5.3 || ^7.4.0" from @angular/common@15.1.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!     @angular/common@"^15.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @angular/common@"15.1.4" from @angular/forms@15.1.4
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/forms
npm ERR!       @angular/forms@"^15.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!       1 more (@ionic/angular)
npm ERR!     3 more (@angular/platform-browser, ...)
npm ERR!   5 more (@angular/core, @angular/forms, @angular/router, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer rxjs@"^5.5.11" from @ionic-native/core@4.20.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@ionic-native/core
npm ERR!   peer @ionic-native/core@"^4.11.0" from @ionic-native/social-sharing@4.20.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@ionic-native/social-sharing
npm ERR!     @ionic-native/social-sharing@"^4.20.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: rxjs@5.5.12
npm ERR! node_modules/rxjs
npm ERR!   peer rxjs@"^5.5.11" from @ionic-native/core@4.20.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@ionic-native/core
npm ERR!     peer @ionic-native/core@"^4.11.0" from @ionic-native/social-sharing@4.20.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/@ionic-native/social-sharing
npm ERR!       @ionic-native/social-sharing@"^4.20.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Comment: Have you tried

`npm i @ionic-native/social-sharing --legacy-peer-deps`

?

Answer (score 0):

Delete the node_modules folder and redo

> npm i

then install the component with:

> npm i @ionic-native/social-sharing

Comment: I tried it. Sadly I cant use npm i. I edited the question to show you what error I got

Comment: Delete also the file package-lock.json and test. If you still get the error, check the versions of the package.json and changes "rxjs": "7.5.7" by ~7.5.0. Delete the node_modulles and package-lock again and run npm i

Comment: Changing the rxjs version didnt do anything. Deleting package-lock.json also didnt work. Im getting the same error with different rxjs versions